# DRY looping for Active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, loops, dry

I am building a API for a application and am using the code below to generate some JSON.

```
 Catagory.all.as_json(include: { questions: { include: :answers, only: [:title, :question_type]}}, only: :name)
```

The returns something that looks like this.

```
[{"name"=>"music", "questions"=>[{"title"=>"somethings", "question_type"=>"text", "answers"=>[{"id"=>1, "question_id"=>1, "text"=>"something", "correct"=>true, "created_at"=>Mon, 22 Sep 2014 22:19:15 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Mon, 22 Sep 2014 22:19:15 UTC +00:00}, {"id"=>2, "question_id"=>1, "text"=>"something", "correct"=>true, "created_at"=>Tue, 23 Sep 2014 16:01:40 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Tue, 23 Sep 2014 16:01:40 UTC +00:00}]}]}]
```

This is great but I wanted to remove the "created_at", "updated_at" and ID's. I found a method of doing it but it does not feel very DRY. Feels too repetitive.

```
Catagory.all.as_json(include: { questions: { include: :answers, only: [:title, :question_type]}}, only: :name).each {|a| a['questions'].each {|w| w['answers'].each {|f| f.delete('created_at')}}}.each {|c| c['questions'].each {|y| y['answers'].each {|b| b.delete('updated_at')}}}.each {|l| l['questions'].each {|x| x['answers'].each {|z| z.delete('id')}}}.each {|g| g['questions'].each {|h| h['answers'].each {|r| r.delete('question_id')}}}
```

I find its also not very good for readability.

Thanks

Comment: could you mention what you used, that way you won't get same method in as reply :)

Comment: I would like to see where the method `as_json` is documented too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path, I'm not sure why you didn't figure this out yourself. You can change your query to this:

```
Catagory.all.as_json(include: { questions: { include: { answers: { only: [:question_id, :text, :correct]} }, only: [:title, :question_type]}}, only: :name)
```

And if you're using this query frequently then please put it within a scope inside `Category` class.

Comment: This method I never saw. +1

Comment: Ok.. I sent you request to FB, to keep in touch.:-)

Comment: @Surya Thanks, I kept trying to play with the `only:` part but couldn't work it out. Excellent :)